# If someone share document how to get send email by external api notification

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I want to make a workflow that
If someone shares a document in the library with another user then he receives an email through an external API. Then what would be the condition to start the flow?

Comment: Leave a bit more information for reviewers.  For instance, what API?  Additionally, I'm unclear if you are asking how to work with APIs in Automate or if you need to know which trigger to use.

Comment: @JennyHersko I'm not the asker. Looking at the tags, this Q is not about Power Automate, but on-premises SharePoint with legacy workflows.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trigger that can fire when a document is shared.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/SharePoint-when-a-file-folder-is-shared-trigger/idi-p/326018